# dropdown selection not changing values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a drop down which I have created using ul li on selection it will be changing values of the second selection bar now the problem is that when the values of second selection bar is changed then the selection bar is not working for me can anyone help me out with this concern.

let suppose if a user does not make any selection within first option and he selects bedrooms it is working perfectly but when ever user tries to change selection from condo house or office the values in second selection bar will be changed and when the values are changed then user is unable to make selection in the second field make sense I am not good in explaining if you  can look and make selection you will understand my question can any one would be able to help me out with this concern ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mc-select').on('click', function() {
     $('.mc-options', this).toggle();
    });
});

$('.htype_opt').on('click', function() {
 var mc_val = $(this).attr('data-type');
 $('#htype').text(mc_val);
 $('.htype').val(mc_val);
 
 if(mc_val == 'Condo') {
  $('.dt_bed_ch').text('Studio');
  var new_ul_data = '<li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="0">Studio</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="1">1 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="2">2 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="3">3 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="4">4 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="5">5 Bedroom</li>';
  $('.dt_bed').html(new_ul_data);
 }
 
 if(mc_val == 'House') {
  $('.dt_bed_ch').text('1 Bedroom');
  var new_ul_data = '<li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="1">1 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="2">2 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="3">3 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="4">4 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="5">5 Bedroom</li>';
  $('.dt_bed').html(new_ul_data);
 }
 
 if(mc_val == 'Office') {
  $('.dt_bed_ch').text('Open space');
  var new_ul_data = '<li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="0">Open space</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="1">1 Room</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="2">2 Rooms</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="3">3 Rooms</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="4">4 Rooms</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="5">5 Rooms</li>';
  $('.dt_bed').html(new_ul_data);
 }
 
 var type   = mc_val;
 var city   = $('.city').val();
 var bedroom  = $('.bedroom').val();
 var bathroom = $('.bathroom').val();
 var area   = $('.area').val();
 var pkg   = $('.pkg').val();
 
 $.ajax({
  type   : "POST",
  url    : "http://bluevisionarydesigns.com/demo/unick/home/get_data",
  dataType : "text",
  data  : {city: city, type : mc_val, bedroom : bedroom, bathroom : bathroom, area : area, pkg : pkg},
  success  : function(data) {
   $('.estimate-amount').text(data);
  }
 });
});

$('.bedroom_opt').on('click', function() {
 var mc_val  = $(this).attr('data-bedroom');
 var mc_val2 = $(this).text();
 $('#bedroom').text(mc_val2);
 $('.bedroom').val(mc_val);
 
 alert(mc_val);
 var type   = $('.htype').val();
 var city   = $('.city').val();
 var bedroom  = mc_val;
 var bathroom = $('.bathroom').val();
 var area   = $('.area').val();
 var pkg   = $('.pkg').val();
 
 $.ajax({
  type   : "POST",
  url    : "http://bluevisionarydesigns.com/demo/unick/home/get_data",
  dataType : "text",
  data  : {city: city, type : type, bedroom : mc_val, bathroom : bathroom, area : area, pkg : pkg},
  success  : function(data) {
   $('.estimate-amount').text(data);
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.search-bar form .input-group .mc-select {
    position: relative;
}

.mc-select {
    min-width: 100px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #dce1e5;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.mc-select .mc-value {
    height: 62px;
    line-height: 62px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.mc-select .mc-options {
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    -webkit-transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
    -moz-transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
    -ms-transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
    -o-transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
    transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-1px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-1px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-1px);
    transform: translateX(-1px);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-left: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    display:none;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-bar">
<form method="POST">
   <!-- =========================================================== -->
   <div class="input-group ">
    <div class="mc-select">
     <div class="mc-value" id="htype">Condo</div>
     <ul class="mc-options">
      <li class="mc-option htype_opt" data-type="Condo">Condo</li>
      <li class="mc-option htype_opt" data-type="House">House</li>
      <li class="mc-option htype_opt" data-type="Office">Office</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="htype" class="htype" value="Condo" />
   </div> <!-- End of input Group -->
   
   <!-- =========================================================== -->
   <div class="input-group ">
    <div class="mc-select">
     <div class="mc-value dt_bed_ch" id="bedroom">Studio</div>
     <ul class="mc-options dt_bed">
      <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="0">Studio</li>
      <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="1">1 Bedroom</li>
      <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="2">2 Bedroom</li>
      <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="3">3 Bedroom</li>
      <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="4">4 Bedroom</li>
      <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="5">5 Bedroom</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="bedroom" class="bedroom" value="0" />
   </div> <!-- End of input Group -->
      </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the selection in the first dropdown, you're creating brand new `<li>` elements in the second dropdown. These elements do not have any "click" event bound to them, so when the user selects them, nothing happens.

This is because the elements did not exist when you ran the code:

```
$('.bedroom_opt').on('click', function() {
...
```

which attached the click event handler to all the existing `<li>` elements with the bedroom_opt class.

To get round this, you can use event delegation:

```
$('.dt_bed').on('click', '.bedroom_opt', function() {
```

This attaches the event handler to the dt_bed element, which always exists, but then delegates any click events which occur on it down to the specified elements below it (in this case, elements with the bedroom_opt class), and it does this dynamically whenever the event is handled, so it can cope with elements added at any time.

For more info, see http://api.jquery.com/on/ and read the section entitled "Direct and delegated events"

Comment: This makes debugging more difficult, because the `click` handler will not show as an event listener on the `.bedroom_opt` element.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen interesting perspective, if that's true I hadn't thought of that. It's pretty common practise though and very well documented by jQuery, and of course is also possible without jQuery if you so choose. It doesn't seem to put people off using it!

Comment: Common practice `!==` best practice.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen true enough. C.F. the number of questions on here every day which are vulnerable to SQL injection, despite the wealth of info and examples on the topic spread across the web. Anyway, I agree it could make debugging more difficult, but in real life it's never been a critical issue for any work I've been involved with. The intended flow is fairly obvious from the code. As I mentioned in the comment on your post, I'd be quite interested in what the most performant version is, especially on a busy page. Something to try another time...

Comment: I'd be surprised if attaching to parent elements was more performant. We must have quite different jobs, because event handling is a big part of my work!

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen I would guess it depends if removing the handlers on the previously existing elements takes time. Again, I suspect it would all depends on the number of affected elements at any given moment. Actually, do you even need to remove those handlers, if the elements have been removed from the DOM? BTW My job is pretty much covering the full MS stack, a lot of code reviews and design reviews, with a bit of high-level architecture thrown in, so I don't get massively involved in the fine detail of UI development so much any more, except in personal projects

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen that said, I take your point about a practise which potentially impedes debugging, I would want to sort that out if I thought it was getting in the way of my team's progress or jepoardising future maintenance efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, just needed to attach the event listener for `.bedroom_opt` after you generate the HTML for it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mc-select').on('click', function() {
    $('.mc-options', this).toggle();
  });


  $('.htype_opt').on('click', function() {
    var mc_val = $(this).attr('data-type');
    $('#htype').text(mc_val);
    $('.htype').val(mc_val);

    if (mc_val == 'Condo') {
      $('.dt_bed_ch').text('Studio');
      var new_ul_data = '<li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="0">Studio</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="1">1 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="2">2 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="3">3 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="4">4 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="5">5 Bedroom</li>';
      $('.dt_bed').html(new_ul_data);
    }

    if (mc_val == 'House') {
      $('.dt_bed_ch').text('1 Bedroom');
      var new_ul_data = '<li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="1">1 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="2">2 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="3">3 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="4">4 Bedroom</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="5">5 Bedroom</li>';
      $('.dt_bed').html(new_ul_data);
    }

    if (mc_val == 'Office') {
      $('.dt_bed_ch').text('Open space');
      var new_ul_data = '<li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="0">Open space</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="1">1 Room</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="2">2 Rooms</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="3">3 Rooms</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="4">4 Rooms</li><li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="5">5 Rooms</li>';
      $('.dt_bed').html(new_ul_data);
    }

    var type = mc_val;
    var city = $('.city').val();
    var bedroom = $('.bedroom').val();
    var bathroom = $('.bathroom').val();
    var area = $('.area').val();
    var pkg = $('.pkg').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://bluevisionarydesigns.com/demo/unick/home/get_data",
      dataType: "text",
      data: {
        city: city,
        type: mc_val,
        bedroom: bedroom,
        bathroom: bathroom,
        area: area,
        pkg: pkg
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.estimate-amount').text(data);
      }
    });


    $('.bedroom_opt').off('click').on('click', function() {
      var mc_val = $(this).attr('data-bedroom');
      var mc_val2 = $(this).text();
      $('#bedroom').text(mc_val2);
      $('.bedroom').val(mc_val);

      alert(mc_val);
      var type = $('.htype').val();
      var city = $('.city').val();
      var bedroom = mc_val;
      var bathroom = $('.bathroom').val();
      var area = $('.area').val();
      var pkg = $('.pkg').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://bluevisionarydesigns.com/demo/unick/home/get_data",
        dataType: "text",
        data: {
          city: city,
          type: type,
          bedroom: mc_val,
          bathroom: bathroom,
          area: area,
          pkg: pkg
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.estimate-amount').text(data);
        }
      });
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.search-bar form .input-group .mc-select {
  position: relative;
}

.mc-select {
  min-width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #dce1e5;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.mc-select .mc-value {
  height: 62px;
  line-height: 62px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.mc-select .mc-options {
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  -webkit-transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
  -moz-transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
  -ms-transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
  -o-transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
  transition: height 350ms 0s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-1px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-1px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-1px);
  transform: translateX(-1px);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
  border-right: 0 solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-bar">
  <form method="POST">
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <div class="input-group ">
      <div class="mc-select">
        <div class="mc-value" id="htype">Condo</div>
        <ul class="mc-options">
          <li class="mc-option htype_opt" data-type="Condo">Condo</li>
          <li class="mc-option htype_opt" data-type="House">House</li>
          <li class="mc-option htype_opt" data-type="Office">Office</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="htype" class="htype" value="Condo" />
    </div>
    <!-- End of input Group -->

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <div class="input-group ">
      <div class="mc-select">
        <div class="mc-value dt_bed_ch" id="bedroom">Studio</div>
        <ul class="mc-options dt_bed">
          <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="0">Studio</li>
          <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="1">1 Bedroom</li>
          <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="2">2 Bedroom</li>
          <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="3">3 Bedroom</li>
          <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="4">4 Bedroom</li>
          <li class="mc-option bedroom_opt" data-bedroom="5">5 Bedroom</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="bedroom" class="bedroom" value="0" />
    </div>
    <!-- End of input Group -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Note that you have to remove all previous event listeners using `.off('click')`. There are other ways to do this, but I would rather avoid attaching listeners to items they are not intended for (as in attaching to `document`). Attaching the event to the item it is intended for makes debugging easier, because it shows the listener as attached to the element inside of dev tools.

Comment: it will work but event delegation is neater and less verbose than the off-then-on method. It would be interesting to know which performs better.

Comment: @ADyson, hardly more verbose! They are nearly the same number of characters. This has the advantage of helping the developer understand the order of the code, and also shows the `click` event listener under the dev tools. Attaching it to the document just creates another layer of indirection and hurts future debugging.

Comment: I meant less verbose in the sense of less commands being executed, rather than a literal character count (which is only possible to be similar because jquery happens to support method chaining)

Answer (score 1):

One thumb rule, Whenever you have to **bind any event** to any element which comes in **future** in the DOM, i,e, Not available at the time click or any event is bind then you should bind it using below methd.

```
$("body").on('click', 'selector',callback);

In your case $("body").on('click', '.bedroom_opt',function(){...});
```

Comment: This I think is a better solution, it comes really handy when working with ASP.NET UpdatePanels.